# query sql server 2012 change to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
select  produksi.thntanam,
        tanggal
  from  (SELECT  datepart(d,IndividualDate) as tanggal,
                 datepart(m,IndividualDate) as bulan
           FROM  DateRange('d', '$tanggalawal', '$tanggalakhir')
        ) daftarTgl
    inner join (select  b.thn_tanam as thntanam,
                        datepart(d,a.tgl_panen) tgl,
                        datepart(m,a.tgl_panen) bln
                  from  dbo.tp_produksi_pemanen a
                    left join tr_blok b on a.id_blok = b.id_blok
                  WHERE a.nama_pemanen='" . $row['namapem'] . "' and
                        ISNUMERIC(a.nik_pemanen ) = 1 and
                        a.id_satuan_unit_afd ='" . $id_afd . "'
                  group by b.thn_tanam, datepart(d,a.tgl_panen), datepart(m,a.tgl_panen)
               ) produksi on daftarTgl.tanggal = produksi.tgl and daftarTgl.bulan = produksi.bln";
```

This is my question in SQL Server 2012 and I want to use this code in sql server 2008

but it does not work

Can you help me to change to the sql server 2008 ??

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This code looks very much like PHP and not pure SQL

Comment: Is `DateRange` a function you've created?

Comment: This code will work in SQL Server 2008 - the problem could be because you have not created the `DateRange` function on your SQL Server 2008 database (as indicated by @vercelli).  In addition you should really use parameterised SQL in your PHP code to avoid SQL injection issues.